# jQuery group similar items with headings

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to group similar items based on data attr, when grouped it should show two headings extracted from data attr of each item.

So far I can get one heading (group name) but **unable to append the second one (type name).**

Any help would be really appreciated.

*Example: Trying to achieve the following*

```
GROUP
TYPE
item 1
item 2
item 3

GROUP
TYPE
item 1
item 2
item 3
```

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
var $list = $('#group');
    var lists = {};
    var $newLists = $();

    $list.children().each( function () {
        var group = $( this ).data('group');
        if (!lists[group]) lists[group] = [];
        lists[group].push(this);
    });

    $.each( lists, function (group, items) {
        var $newList = $('<div class="row"/>').append(items).prepend("<h3>"+ group +"</h3>");
        $newLists = $newLists.add($newList);
    });

    $list.replaceWith($newLists);  
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group">

<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 1</div>
</div>

<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 2</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 3</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 4</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 5</div>
</div>

<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 1</div>
</div>

<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 2</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 3</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 4</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 5</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

possible work around would be

```js
jQuery(function ($) {
var $list = $('#group');
    var lists = {};
    var $newLists = $();

    $list.children().each( function () {
        var group = $( this ).data('group');
        if (!lists[group]) lists[group] = [];
        lists[group].push(this);
    });

    $.each( lists, function (group, items) {
        var $newList = $('<div class="row"/>').append(items).prepend("<h3>"+ group +"</h3>" 
        +"<h3>"+
        $(this).attr("data-type") + "</h3>"
        
        );
        $newLists = $newLists.add($newList);
    });

    $list.replaceWith($newLists);  
 
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group">

<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 1</div>
</div>

<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 2</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 3</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 4</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
  <div>item 5</div>
</div>

<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 1</div>
</div>

<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 2</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 3</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 4</div>
</div>
<div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
  <div>item 5</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would have written the code for such a requirement.

- Select all targeted div's using `$("#group > div")`
- Iterating over these div's, insert the `h3` group or `h4` type before the div if the previous type or group value does not match the current value.

This compresses the code quite a bit. Here's how your code looks with this logic:

```
var previousGroup = "";
var previousType = "";

$("#group > div").each(function() {
    var group = $(this).data("group");
    var type = $(this).data("type");

    if(previousGroup != group) {
        $(this).before("<h3>" + group + "</h3>");
        previousGroup = group;
    }

    if(previousType != type) {
        $(this).before("<h4>" + type + "</h4>");
        previousType = type;
    }
});
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var previousGroup = "";
  var previousType = "";

  $("#group > div").each(function() {
    var group = $(this).data("group");
    var type = $(this).data("type");
    
    if(previousGroup != group) {
      $(this).before("<h3>" + group + "</h3>");
      previousGroup = group;
    }
    
    if(previousType != type) {
      $(this).before("<h4>" + type + "</h4>");
      previousType = type;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="group">

  <div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
    <div>item 1</div>
  </div>

  <div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
    <div>item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
    <div>item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
    <div>item 4</div>
  </div>
  <div data-group="GROUP A" data-type="Construction">
    <div>item 5</div>
  </div>

  <div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
    <div>item 1</div>
  </div>

  <div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
    <div>item 2</div>
  </div>
  <div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
    <div>item 3</div>
  </div>
  <div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
    <div>item 4</div>
  </div>
  <div data-group="GROUP B" data-type="Finance">
    <div>item 5</div>
  </div>

</div>
```